# Hudson - TestNG - Using DataProvider- Showing same test name for all data values

Tags: testing, hudson

I am running my testng tests from Hudson. Running around 2000 tests (i.e 2000 datasets passed to a single testcase).
In Hudson report it is displaying the testcasename and some time facing issue for what data it failed. I want to override that so that it should show the name i required , instead of same name for entire my dataset.

Thanks
Madan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by implementing ITest and overriding the getTestName method.  You can use factory based on your dataprovider on the constructor of the class which would set the variable testname and getTestName should return this name that you want in the output.